# Which are the default features enabled on the main three Lightning Network node implementations (LND, C-Lightning and Eclair)?

Tags: lightning-network, network, lightning-network-daemon, core-lightning, eclair

Which are the default features enabled on the main three Lightning Network node implementations (LND, C-Lightning and Eclair)? I mean the features shown when you use "describegraph" command.